# Weird django URL problem

Tags: django

If i go to www.mysite.com/login, everything displays like it should.

But when i want to go from mysite.com/login to mysite.com/register, i end up in mysite.com/login/register.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without some code but I guess on your login site you have a link like:

```
<a href="register/">Register</a>
```

which should probably be

```
<a href="{% url name_of_register_url %}>Register</a>
```

Can you provide your `url.py` and the HTML code for that link?

Comment: The important thing to note is that a `href` that's not beginning with a `/` is relative to the current page.

Comment: misterwebz: don't forget to select Felix's answer as the solution.  It will help his reputation and close out the question.

Comment: Forgot about that. I'll do it immediately.